# The sum of a 2D arrays' specific rows - Python

Tags: python, arrays, 2d, file-handling

Trying to get this program to print the sum of each row, then the total sum of all the elements, it's fine with the grand total but I can't see why the individual sums of the rows aren't outputting correctly

```
rows = len(numbers)
cols = len(numbers[0])
total=0
```

The variables are set as above (each column is of the same length, and the array is entirely integers)

I want it to run through each row, add each column within that row and print it, then print the total of the whole array.

```
for x in range(0, rows):
  rowtotal=0
  for y in range(0, cols):
    rowtotal=rowtotal+int(numbers[x-1][y-1])
  print(rowtotal)
  total=total+rowtotal
print(total)
```

The array is imported through
`import sys
numbers= sys.argv[1:]
for i in range(0,len(numbers)): 
  numbers[i]= numbers[i].split(',')`

I'm coding through an online software which may be the problem. Currently it returns

> Program Failed for Input: 1,1,-2 -1,-2,-3 1,1,1
>   Expected Output: 
>   0
>   -6
>   3
>   -3
>   Your Program Output:
>   3
>   0
>   -6
>   -3

Any other code, including `numbers[x][y]` seems to always return an error

Comment: Can you print the array numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `numbers[x][y]` instead of `numbers[x-1][y-1]`.

So if you do:

```
numbers=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
rows = len(numbers)
cols = len(numbers[0])
total=0
for x in range(0, rows):
    rowtotal=0
    for y in range(0, cols):
        rowtotal=rowtotal+int(numbers[x][y])
    print(rowtotal)
    total=total+rowtotal
print(total)
```

the output is

```
6
15
24
33
78
```

Also if the array `numbers` consists only of integers, you can remove the `int` from `int(numbers[x][y])`.

Comment: Thanks but that returns the error IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Did you define the 2D array numbers properly? I added a running example to the answer. I run it and it worked for me.

Comment: The array is imported (is that the correct term?)  i've edited the question

Comment: Can you add an example of the array to the question? It sounds like maybe the format of the array cause problems. That is, print the array numbers.

Comment: There are no numbers to print? Also if i remove the int() there is a 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' I do my coding through an online software so maybe thats the problem? I'm really confused....